# Select in bold a specific <li> into a React map

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a design system in order to have all the design available in one web app with React. In it, there is a side bar with all the topics that I retrieve from a Json file. I want to put in bold the topic `<li>` when I click on it. But when I click, all the `<li>` turn in bold and when I click on the next one, it turn in "normal" whereas it should turn in bold

I did a state with selected: false and a handleClick with the setState as `!this.state.selected`. I retrieve all the `<li>` tags from a Json file and I need to map them from it.

```
export default class MainMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected: false
        };
    }
    handleClick = () => { 
        this.setState({
            selected: !this.state.selected
        })
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <div className="MainMenu" > 
        {
            Data.map(
                (item, index) => <div key={index}>
                    <h2 className="Title" >{item.group}</h2>
                    <ul className="List"> 
                        {item.pages.map((page, i) => <li key={i} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} style={ this.state.selected? { fontWeight: 'normal' } : { fontWeight: 'bold' } }><Link to={page.url} className="ListItem">{page.name}</Link></li>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect to put in bold only the `<li>` when I click on it and not all the `<li>`

Comment: So they all work off the one state? You could give them each an id equal to one of the properties i.e ```page.name``` and change the handleclick to toggle the styling instead?

Comment: Thanks @Mick. yes they are all in the same state. You mean give them to each an ID in my son file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save an id of each item you want to have bold style applied to to the state. This will allow having more than one bold item at a time:

```
this.state = {
  selected: []
};

// ...
// Remove bold type if already active, otherwise add bold type
handleClick = id => {
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.selected.includes(id)) {
        return state.selected.filter(item => item !== id);
      }
      return [...state.selected, id];
    });
  };

// ...
 Data.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <h2 className="Title">{item.group}</h2>
        <ul className="List">
          {item.pages.map((page, i) => (
            <li
              key={i}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
              style={
                this.state.selected.includes(i)
                  ? { fontWeight: "normal" }
                  : { fontWeight: "bold" }
              }
            >
              <Link to={page.url} className="ListItem">
                {page.name}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is relative to your `MainMenu` component, meaning it will always be the same for every list item. You need a way to know exactly which item is selected, so you can't just save a boolean value. You could instead save the index of the selected item in your state. Then, you can check if each item's index is equal to the index saved in the state to know if that item is selected or not:

```
export default class MainMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: -1 // starts as -1 since that's an invalid index
    };
  }
  handleClick = (index) => { 
    this.setState({
      selected: index
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="MainMenu" > 
        {Data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <h2 className="Title" >
              {item.group}
            </h2>
            <ul className="List"> 
              {item.pages.map((page, i) => (
                <li
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
                  style={ this.state.selected === i ? { fontWeight: 'normal' } : { fontWeight: 'bold' } }
                >
                  <Link to={page.url} className="ListItem">
                    {page.name}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this limit it to only ever having one item in bold though?

Comment: Yes it would, it wasn't clear from the post if that was a requirement. The other answer by Clarity allows for multiple items to be selected.

Comment: Indeed, I iterate on a Json file. So I need to change bold only one item when I click on it and not all